# Adding custom buttons to the about dialog in eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to customize the about dialog in my eclipse RCP application. I already managed to add my logo and to replace the title and the text body as described under [Branding Your Application](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Branding/branding-your-application.html).

I would also like to add some buttons to it: send a feedback or open the wiki page etc.
Is there a way to do it or achieve a similar functionality?

Any help is much appreciated.

[image: About dialog in eclipse rcp]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The About diaog (`org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.AboutDialog`) does not support any configuration.

The 'feature image row' you have highlighted is populated from the `IBundleGroupProvider` array returned by `Platform.getBundleGroupProviders()`, I don't see any way to add to this.